# Расчет процентной высоты с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, вёрстка

Будет трудно описать, но я попробую. Есть `header` и `footer`, которые спозиционированы фиксировано. В блоке контента есть верхний и нижний отступ. Под верхним отступом, а следовательно и под `header'ом` есть блок с текстом. После текстового блока идет блок, назовем его `row`, c колонками - `col`. В каждом из `col` есть верхняя часть - это картинка заданная `backgound'ом` и нижняя часть - это блоки информации. Вопрос: как с помощью js высчитать все `margin`, `padding` и `height`, что бы блоки `col` были "резиновыми".

*P.S. Скриншот прототипа* [image: скриншот прототипа]

Comment: Не надо использовать js.

Answer (score 3):

Если нет в планах использовать какую-нибудь готовую библиотеку типа [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/css/), можно воспользоваться парой трюков css, но уж точно не js. Вот самый простецкий пример на css [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HellLena/epzz4n2r/3/):

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#header, #content, .row, #footer {
  border:1px solid black;
}
.row::after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
}
.col {
  width:33.33%;
  border:1px solid red;
  float:left;
}
```

Высота будет формироваться в зависимости от содержимого. Так же можно задать параметр min-width. Так же можно задать параметр, чтобы для определённой величины экрана колонки смещались одна под одну и занимали 100% ширины. Короче, по принципу того, как это делается в той же сетке в Bootstrap.